# Issue using Make when compiling Bitcoind

Tags: makefile, bitcoin, bitcoind

I've been having trouble for almost two days with this issue, where my make crashes shortly after the command. I followed the setup for OSx from the Bitcoin github readme, and executed ./autogen.sh and ./configure just. 
I tried installing gcc, uninstalling and re-installing openssl, and almost anything that occurred to me. Note that the make command runs fine on the master branch, just fails on the latest branches (V0.9.5 in my case). This might or not be an easy fix, but I'm really stumped at this point and appreciate any help. 
Here's the error I'm getting shortly after executing the make command:

```
Making all in src
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make  all-recursive
Making all in .
  CXX      bitcoind.o
In file included from bitcoind.cpp:9:
In file included from ./main.h:13:
./bignum.h:56:24: error: base class has incomplete type
class CBigNum : public BIGNUM
                ~~~~~~~^~~~~~
/usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1d/include/openssl/ossl_typ.h:80:16: note: forward declaration of 'bignum_st'
typedef struct bignum_st BIGNUM;
               ^
In file included from bitcoind.cpp:9:
In file included from ./main.h:13:
./bignum.h:61:9: error: use of undeclared identifier 'BN_init'
        BN_init(this);
        ^
./bignum.h:66:9: error: use of undeclared identifier 'BN_init'
        BN_init(this);
        ^
./bignum.h:67:14: error: no matching function for call to 'BN_copy'
        if (!BN_copy(this, &b))
             ^~~~~~~
/usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1d/include/openssl/bn.h:219:9: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion
      from 'CBigNum *' to 'BIGNUM *' (aka 'bignum_st *') for 1st argument
BIGNUM *BN_copy(BIGNUM *a, const BIGNUM *b);
        ^
In file included from bitcoind.cpp:9:
In file included from ./main.h:13:
./bignum.h:69:13: error: no matching function for call to 'BN_clear_free'
            BN_clear_free(this);
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1d/include/openssl/bn.h:218:6: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion
      from 'CBigNum *' to 'BIGNUM *' (aka 'bignum_st *') for 1st argument
void BN_clear_free(BIGNUM *a);
     ^
In file included from bitcoind.cpp:9:
In file included from ./main.h:13:
./bignum.h:76:14: error: no matching function for call to 'BN_copy'
        if (!BN_copy(this, &b))
             ^~~~~~~
/usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1d/include/openssl/bn.h:219:9: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion
      from 'CBigNum *' to 'BIGNUM *' (aka 'bignum_st *') for 1st argument
BIGNUM *BN_copy(BIGNUM *a, const BIGNUM *b);
        ^
In file included from bitcoind.cpp:9:
In file included from ./main.h:13:
./bignum.h:83:9: error: no matching function for call to 'BN_clear_free'
        BN_clear_free(this);
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1d/include/openssl/bn.h:218:6: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion
      from 'CBigNum *' to 'BIGNUM *' (aka 'bignum_st *') for 1st argument
void BN_clear_free(BIGNUM *a);
     ^
In file included from bitcoind.cpp:9:
In file included from ./main.h:13:
./bignum.h:87:37: error: use of undeclared identifier 'BN_init'
    CBigNum(signed char n)        { BN_init(this); if (n >= 0) setulong(n); else setint64(n); }
                                    ^
./bignum.h:88:37: error: use of undeclared identifier 'BN_init'
    CBigNum(short n)              { BN_init(this); if (n >= 0) setulong(n); else setint64(n); }
                                    ^
./bignum.h:89:37: error: use of undeclared identifier 'BN_init'
    CBigNum(int n)                { BN_init(this); if (n >= 0) setulong(n); else setint64(n); }
                                    ^
./bignum.h:90:37: error: use of undeclared identifier 'BN_init'
    CBigNum(long n)               { BN_init(this); if (n >= 0) setulong(n); else setint64(n); }
                                    ^
./bignum.h:91:37: error: use of undeclared identifier 'BN_init'
    CBigNum(long long n)          { BN_init(this); setint64(n); }
                                    ^
./bignum.h:92:37: error: use of undeclared identifier 'BN_init'
    CBigNum(unsigned char n)      { BN_init(this); setulong(n); }
                                    ^
./bignum.h:93:37: error: use of undeclared identifier 'BN_init'
    CBigNum(unsigned short n)     { BN_init(this); setulong(n); }
                                    ^
./bignum.h:94:37: error: use of undeclared identifier 'BN_init'
    CBigNum(unsigned int n)       { BN_init(this); setulong(n); }
                                    ^
./bignum.h:95:37: error: use of undeclared identifier 'BN_init'
    CBigNum(unsigned long n)      { BN_init(this); setulong(n); }
                                    ^
./bignum.h:96:37: error: use of undeclared identifier 'BN_init'
    CBigNum(unsigned long long n) { BN_init(this); setuint64(n); }
                                    ^
./bignum.h:97:37: error: use of undeclared identifier 'BN_init'
    explicit CBigNum(uint256 n)   { BN_init(this); setuint256(n); }
                                    ^
./bignum.h:101:9: error: use of undeclared identifier 'BN_init'
        BN_init(this);
        ^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
20 errors generated.
make[3]: *** [bitcoind.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

Answer (score -1):

I recently ran into this issue. I re-checked and I made sure that I had the following dependencies set up:

```
$ brew install automake berkeley-db4 libtool boost miniupnpc pkg-config python qt libevent qrencode
$ brew install librsvg
```

After this it worked correctly.